# Output parser of langchain Agent

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, artificial-intelligence, langchain

I am initializing a langchain agent as:

```
agent_output_parser=AgentOutputParser()
     self.mrkl = initialize_agent(
                tools, 
                llm,
                output_parser= agent_output_parser,
                agent_executor_kwargs={ "output_parser": agent_output_parser}
            )
```

I have also created an AgentParser subclass as:

```
class AgentParser(BaseLLMOutputParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
      
    
    def parse(self, text):
        print(text)
        return text
      

    def parse_result(self, output):
        print(output)
        return output
```

However, using print I would expect to see the output of the agent parsed and somehow manipulate it.
In my current code I can't seem to handle the output of the agent and the prints i wrote never happen.
Is there an alternative way to pass a custom output parser?